# How to use a html form to upload a multiple images to a WordPress backend gallery custom field

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, wordpress-plugin-creation, wordperfect

This is a WordPress plugin which is supposed to extract data from a html form and dump it into a custom post type, the post has custom fields like the image which should be displayed once the form is submitted, however while the other custom fields with text seem to be working, the image is not being displayed, below is the function to make a new folder in the upload folder and to retrieve the image from that.

```
if ( is_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploads"]["tmp_name"][0]) ){ 
      $img_dir = trailingslashit( wp_upload_dir()['basedir'] ) . 'reviews/';
      wp_mkdir_p( $img_dir ); 
      $upload_status = array();
            foreach ($_FILES["uploads"]["tmp_name"] as $key => $tmp_name) {
                $file_name = basename($_FILES["uploads"]["name"][$key]);
                $file_type = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $target_path = $img_dir . $file_name;
                    if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_path)) {
                    $upload_status[] = "File uploaded successfully: " . $file_name;
                    } 
                    else {
                    $upload_status[] = "Error uploading file: " . $file_name;
                    } 
    }       if (!empty($upload_status)) {
            // Output upload status messages hereD       
            foreach ($upload_status as $status) { echo $status . "<br>";
            }
    }
}
?>
```

below is how the data is sent to the post

```
if ($post_id) {
update_post_meta($post_id, 'review_images', $upload_status);        
}
```

I tried multiple ways including using the attachment ID however it does not seem to be working, the image should ideally be displayed in the backend WordPress custom field image tag